# Segment Control to control sorting and display

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, swiftui

I tried to use a segment control to control the way of sorting. However, I do not know where to trigger the sorting code.

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: nil, content: {
            Picker("Selected Sort State", selection: $selectedSortState) {
                ForEach(SortState.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { sortState in
                    Text(sortState.rawValue).tag(sortState)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle()).padding(.horizontal)
 }
```

After sorting, it should affect how I display the list:

```
List {
        ForEach(sortedList, id: \.self) { item in
            Text(item.name)
        }
 }
```

The sorting code depends on the selected segment:

```
func getSortedObjs() -> [Item] {
    if selectedSortState == SortState.name {
        return items.sorted { $0.name < $1.name}
    } else {
        return items.sorted { $0.date < $1.date}
    }       
}
```

May I know where should I trigger the function `getSortedObjs()` or should I set the `sortedList` as a `@State` or `@Published` object so that it can be updated properly?

*** Additional Info ***

My original data comes from CoreData. I think this is the reason that I cannot show the sorting results appropriately. The UI sometimes did not update. I am not sure if I should use Predicate, but I am new to that.

```
@FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \MyCoreData.timestamp, ascending: true)],
    animation: .default)

private var sortedList: FetchedResults<Item>
```

Comment: From where `sortedList` get it`s data? from a model or a View?

Comment: it is from CoreData. I tried to do filtering and sorting, but no idea on that. I find that the data itself are sorted / filtered, however, the UI did not update accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this code down, you should use onChange:

---

```
var body: some View {
    
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: nil, content: {

        Picker("Selected Sort State", selection: $selectedSortState) {
            ForEach(SortState.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { sortState in
                Text(sortState.rawValue).tag(sortState)
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle()).padding(.horizontal)
        
    })
    .onChange(of: selectedSortState) { newValue in                // <<: here!
        
        if newValue == SortState.name {
            sortedList = items.sorted { $0.name < $1.name}
        } else {
            sortedList = items.sorted { $0.date < $1.date}
        }
        
    }
    
    List {
            ForEach(sortedList, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
     }
 
}
```